# Trouble with generating PDF file to upload to firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, puppeteer

I'm learning about puppeteer and firebase at the moment. What I am trying to do is create a pdf of a web page and upload to firebase storage. This is my code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const firebase = require('firebase');
require("firebase/storage");

const url = process.argv[2];
if (!url) {
    throw "Please provide URL as a first argument";
}

var firebaseConfig = {
        #Firebase Config Goes here
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


#Function to generate PDF file
async function run () {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //await page.goto(url);
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 60000} );

    //await page.pdf({ path: 'api.pdf', format: 'A4' })

    const myPdf = await page.pdf();
    
     await browser.close()

     return myPdf;
}

const myOutput = run();

#Upload to Firebase based on the instruction here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files
 
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
// Create a reference to 'mountains.jpg'
storageRef.child("Name.pdf").put(myOutput)
```

However, I'm running into this error when executing my code

```
$ node screenshot.js https://google.com
Promise { <pending> }
(node:20636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined
    at C:\Users\ppham\NucampFolder\Test\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.cjs.js:833:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.FbsBlob.getBlob (C:\Users\ppham\NucampFolder\Test\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.cjs.js:832:25)
    at multipartUpload (C:\Users\ppham\NucampFolder\Test\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.cjs.js:1519:24)
    at C:\Users\ppham\NucampFolder\Test\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.cjs.js:2003:31
    at C:\Users\ppham\NucampFolder\Test\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.cjs.js:1900:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
(node:20636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20636) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This looks to imply that myOutput doesn't contain anything. I thought that I have created the pdf file after executing the run() function, assigned it to the myOutput variable and passed it to the upload function? I've been reading the Puppeteer documentation and couldn't find any reason why this wouldn't work. Anyone knows why this is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your code and the example code at https://www.toptal.com/puppeteer/headless-browser-puppeteer-tutorial, for example, is trivial, but there's one significant difference:

`run` is defined as an `async` function -- in the example code, this may be inconsequential, as the last line of the example just calls `run()` and nothing happens afterwards. But, in your code, you expect to do something with that output.  So, you'll need to call it with:

`const myOutput = await run();`

But, Node won't want you to use `await` at the top level -- await can only be used inside an `async` function. So, you can either use `then()` or just define another async wrapper. So, probably something like this:

```
async function runAndUpload() {
    const myOutput = await run();
    console.log(myOutput); //let's make sure there's output
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    storageRef.child("Name.pdf").put(myOutput)
}

runAndUpload();
```

Comment: Thanks!. I made the changes and got this  <br/> $ node screenshot.js https://google.com
<Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 34 0a 25 d3 eb e9 e1 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 2f 43 72 65 61 74 6f 72 20 28 43 68 72 6f 6d 69 75 6d 29 0a 2f 50 72 6f 64 ... 57147 more bytes>
C:\Users\ppham\NucampFolder\Test\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.cjs.js:479
        this.xhr_ = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        ^

ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at new NetworkXhrIo (C:\Users\ppham\NucampFolder\Test\node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.cjs.js:479:25)

Comment: This answer suggests (by inference) that your storage request may only work in the browser and not the Node environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671126/get-downloadurl-keeps-throwing-error-xmlhttprequest-is-not-defined-using-fireb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848132/upload-files-to-firebase-storage-using-node-js

Comment: Thanks for links! I'll check it out.